# Simple Form #input_field method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Using a new/unchanged installation of `simple_form 3.0.0.rc` on `rails 4.0.0.rc1`, this view code

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :email %>
<%= end %>
```

produces this output

```
<input class="string email optional" id="order_email" maxlength="255" name="order[email]" size="255" type="text" />
```

but I had expected the output not to include `maxlength` and to set `type` to 'email', much like the `#input` method does:

```
<input class="string email optional" id="order_email" name="order[email]" type="email" />
```

My expectations come from the fact that `simple_form.rb` includes the following default values:

```
b.use :html5
b.optional :maxlength
```

**What do I need to do to make the `input` attributes from `#input_field` default to the same as `#input`?**

Comment: Try `<%= f.input :email %>`

Comment: Thanks but I specifically don't want to use #input, which is why I'm trying to make #input_field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input field helper method will take hash you pass to it in second argument and turn them info html attributes. Look at the code below, should do the trick:

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
    <%= f.input_field :email, :type => :email, :maxlength => nil %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/master/SimpleForm/FormBuilder%3ainput_field) `input_field` method takes all the options as `input_html` option except `:as, :collection, :label_method, :value_method` keys. I tried adding `:as => :email` but no avail. But you could use `:type => :email` to get `type="email"` in the rendered html. And according to the source of the method it uses some defaults as well.

So for getting the email field:

```
<%= simple_form_for @order do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :email, :type => :email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its related to your database field... I think you have set the databasefield as string, which hast 255 maximum length in general.. This could be the reason why it adds 255 automatically?

Comment: It works as expected for #input, just not for #input_field. You could be right on the 255 but why isn't type being set to email? Thanks.